# Inline setting dotted variables in Helm chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, argocd

I'm installing ArgoCD using Helm chart.

`helm install cd argo/argo-cd --set configs.params."server.insecure"=true` but then I found that "server.insecure" rendered as

```
configs:
  params:
    server:
      insecure: true
```

Instead of

```
configs:
  params:
    server.insecure: true
```

Hence, HTTPS is still enforced

What is the correct way to set dotted variables using inline configuration

Comment: I'd refactor your Helm chart to use a camel-cased name, `serverInsecure`, and avoid this syntax problem.  Also see [Naming Conventions](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/values/#naming-conventions) in the Helm Best Practices documentation page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [The Format and Limitations of `--set`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) in the Helm documentation:

> Sometimes you need to use special characters in your `--set` lines. You can use a backslash to escape the characters; ....
>
> Similarly, you can escape dot sequences as well.... The syntax for `--set nodeSelector."kubernetes\.io/role"=master` becomes:
>
> ```yaml
> nodeSelector:
>   kubernetes.io/role: master
> ```

Remember that backslash is *also* the shell escape character, so you may need to double the backslash to cause it to not be interpreted as part of a special character sequence.  For your use I might write

```bash
helm install ... --set configs.params.server\\.insecure=true
```

I'd also consider having your deployment system write out a YAML (or JSON) file with the settings you need, and passing that as a `helm install -f` external values file.  This is not the only syntactic quirk of `--set` and I've generally found the values-file syntax to be more robust.

```yaml
# deploy-values.yaml
config:
  params:
    server.insecure: true
```

```bash
helm install ... -f deploy-values.yaml
```